# Beautiful Soup 4 not working with Python 3.4.0

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7, python3, pip

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04** **64 bit** Operating System .

I installed *Beautiful Soup 4* using this command :

```
sudo apt-get install python-bs4
```

With **Python 2.7.6** , I had no difficulty importing the `bs4` module.
But when I used **Python 3.4.0** it showed me this error.

```
>>>import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I also tried to install it using **pip**.

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
```

But again it didn't worked with Python 3.4.0.

Right now I have uninstalled pip and also uninstalled Beautiful Soup 4

```
sudo apt-get remove python-bs4
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

What should I do next to properly install Beautiful Soup 4 for both  **Python 2.7.6** and **Python 3.4.0** ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-bs4
```

python3-bs4 is an error-tolerant HTML parser for Python 3. You can see from this that there are two different packages: python-bs4 (for Python 2.x) and python3-bs4 (for Python 3.x), and to prevent you from getting confused there are also two different Integrated Development Environments for Python: IDLE and IDLE 3 to run them in.

Comment: Thank You . I just installed it using the command that you provided and it is working !! I also installed Beautiful Soup 4 for Python 2.7.6 using the old command. Now it is working with both the Python  versions .